# Конец последовательности в массиве типа данных int

Tags: c, массивы

Как определить конец числовой последовательности в массиве типа данных int в языке Си, если размер массива заранее не известен?

Comment: а можно подробнее? что именно нужно, какое ожидаемое поведение. Пока могу сказать, что в С можно узнать размер статического массива, размер динамически созданных массивов узнать не получится, нужно хранить/передавать его отдельно.

Comment: Если размер массива неизвестен — никак. Старайтесь по возможности не допускать ситуаций, когда размер массива неизвестен.

Answer (score 2):

Если это "ваш" массив (Вы его создаете и Вы о нем все знаете), то, как вариант, можно использовать какой-либо признак конца массива - число, которое не участвует в расчетах и не может принадлежать массиву. На примере строк (а это тоже массив байт), таким признаком служит ноль. Если же это не "ваш" массив, то узнать его размер не получится. Хотите динамические массивы - переходите на С++.